# Manage and monitor internet traffic in remote computers

Tags: internet, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a main PC that connects to network by wireless and get internet by a VPN. 5 PCs connect to this computer by remote desktop and use internet from main PC.

How can I **monitor internet traffic**? Is there any application to do this? Monitoring should preferably take place **per user** – but **per PC** would be sufficient as well.

All computers are running Windows 7. We have a certain limited account for per user; but when in remote, one of users connect to VPN, others can use his account and they are connected. In this case, admin can not find out traffic used by per user?

I want a solution that admin be able to find out traffic of per user or a solution by which a user not be able to connect by other's VPN in remote desktop.

Comment: I'm neither a network specialist nor a Windows user, so I've never used any software for that. But with the details now being clearer, someone familiar with the issue can give a recommendation. I've just voted to have your question reopened, so answers become possible again. Good luck!

Comment: After your edits one thing is still unclear to me: do you want to detect *what* they are doing, or do you want to measure their data usage?

Comment: Still unclear: What do you mean by "manage" and "monitor"? Please list all of the action you want to be able to do. For instance: reboot, add users, read free disk space, take screenshot, etc.

Comment: i want just measure their data usage